# FME Form (Desktop) - Dissolver Transformer Generates Redundant Remnants

Tags: fme-form, dissolve

I have line geometry that I buffered with 50 feet buffer. Now I need to dissolve common boundaries for overlapped polygons, to reduce the size of the file in general.

1. Source lines

[image]

2. Buffer

[image]

"Dissolver" transformer generates remnants:

3. Remnants at the borders of buffers

[image]

In the end, dissolved area was also generated:

[image]

First try was for simpler area. And it took many hours to run. Now I need to process huge area. It took few days. In the end it has failed with no detailed explanation: "Error running translation." and the same warnings about unexpected linear remnants.

"Shapefile Writer: Feature type 'OH_Pri_and_Sec_buffered_AOI_50_dis_remnants' received an incompatible geometry type 'Line', expected 'Polygon'. The following feature cannot be written to this file and will be discarded.
... Last line repeated 1287 times ..."

I thought that my initial buffered data includes some wrong linear geometry that is not accepted by dissolver and added "Geometry Filter". But looks like this is Dissolver issue.

[image]

[image]

FME version 2020.2.

Why I am getting remnants if buffers were generated by FME itself?
How to get rid of those remnants and speed up the process?

Could you help, please?

Comment: When I buffer this I also introduce the generalizer this cuts out many vertices but depending on the method can keep the original shape https://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME-Form-Documentation/FME-Transformers/Transformers/generalizer.htm just using this can speed up the entire process. Try a sample area first to get the results you are after.

Answer (score 0):

I would dissolve the data at the "bufferer" level. This screenshot is using FME Desktop 2022, but I think it should be valid for 2020 as well. Use the "fme_feature_type" as the attribute to chose from. this way you won't have to worry about any byproduct data.

[image]